# creating CMS with PHP and VBulletinuser system

Tags: php, content-management-system, vbulletin

I was wondering if anyone could point me towards some resources about developing systems that incorporate VB user system? My client requested me to develop a PHP system for content management that uses the VB user system for commenting, logging in, etc. Any resources would be appreciated

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vBulletin offers a "Data Manager".

With this you can do the most things like add users, posts, threads and a lot more.

Read the documentation for more:
https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/data_manager_programming

To login into vBulletin from a non vB Page is a bit more difficult.

You need to change the current directory to your forum path with `chdir('/home/forum/')` and then include/require the globlal.php

A full example can you find here http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=108026 for vB 3.x.
But for vBulletin 4.x it should be similar.